# Jenkins job level permission

Tags: devops

How can I enable job level permission on Jenkins? Means I have 10 Jenkins job in my Jenkins installation. I may need to enable user1 only access three jobs our of this 10 and user 2 will access only 5 jobs from this 10 etc?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Jenkins - Config global security - find a section "authorization" and choose "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy". Then add users and mark "OVerrall - Read" permission.
Then go to specific jobs and select "Use project-based security"

Comment: Of course, btw this is one of the basic plugins which you installing during setup if I'm not wrong